# Run python script inside /etc/rc.local doesn't work

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, python, amazon-ami, rc.local

I modified /etc/rc.local on my Amazon AWS AMI

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /var/lock/subsys/local
# setup hostname properly
/usr/bin/python /root/automation/initSystem.py
```

so last line calls Python script that does configuration (Env variables, hostname, networking settings etc) and then does /etc/init.d/network restart

if I run rc.local manually
/etc/rc.local
everything is just fine

when system auto starts it doesn't work. So touch command (2nd line - worked), but python script is never executed, at least results of it's execution (setting up a hostname and restarting network interface seems doesn't work at all)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't debug a mystery script. Does running the python script work with an empty environment? Try:

```
env -i /usr/bin/python /root/automation/initSystem.py
```

Modify your script to capture the output of your command in the script:

```
/usr/bin/python /root/automation/initSystem.py > /root/init.stdout 2> /root/init.stderr
```

and it'll probably contain hints as to why it failed.

Comment: found the error with env -i :) thanks a LOT